# UITableView beginUpdates / endUpdates make typing slower

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using a `UITableView` with a `UITextView` in each cell that increases/reduces its height to fit the text while typing. To accomplish this I update the `UITableView` in the `-textViewDidChange:` delegate method by writing:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Everything works pretty well. However, I notice that typing become slower (iPhone 4 to be specific). My method to calculate the height just return a `CGFloat` by applying `-sizeToFit` method to the text in the `UITextView`. I removed this code and nothing changes that's why I'm sure the problem is in beginUpdates/beginUpdates methods. My question is if there is a way to accomplish this in a efficient way? I'd not like to leave that way.

**EDIT**

CODE:

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    [self adjustTextViewHeightToString:textView];
}

- (void)adjustTextViewHeightToString:(UITextView *)textview
{
     CGFloat width = textview.frame.size.width;

     [textview setScrollEnabled:NO];
     [textview sizeToFit];
     [textview setFrame:CGRectMake(textview.frame.origin.x, textview.frame.origin.y, width, textview.frame.size.height)];
}
```

Comment: Can you provide all the relevant code? In particular the code in `textViewDidChange:`

Comment: I added some code. Thanks.

Comment: Why is your beginUpdates/endUpdates block empty?

Comment: If I update a specific `UITableViewCell` the `UITextView` stops being the first responder.

Comment: Did you try to call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` between beginUpdates/endUpdates calls?

Comment: Yes. And like I said in my comment before the `UITextView` stops being the first responder.

Comment: Try the way I posted in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alexander Karaberov ´s answer is quiet well and **helped me a lot**. But I ended implementing:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    UITextPosition *position = textView.endOfDocument;
    CGRect currectRect       = [textView caretRectForPosition:position];

    if(currectRect.origin.x == 0)
    {
        [self adjustTextViewHeightToString:textView];
    }
}
```

When the `currentRect.origin.x` equals 0 means that the cursos is at the end of the frame and in this case I invoke the `adjustTextViewHeightToString:` method to resize the `UITextView`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you change `textView` height every time you type or delete a character - it is not very efficient, especially if you will type very quickly. At first you shouldn't call `beginUpdates & endUpdates` unless you are inserting, deleting or selecting rows. As said in docs: `beginUpdates
Begin a series of method calls that insert, delete, or select rows and sections of the receiver.` and you are doing neither of these.

Second: try in your `-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView` check whether the text doesn't fit the line and only if yes then increase the height:

Create a `CGRect` variable and initially store `CGRectZero` in it somewhere in `viewWillAppear` like this: `previousRect = CGRectZero;` and then in delegate method:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {

UITextPosition* pos = textView.endOfDocument;
CGRect currentRect = [textView caretRectForPosition:pos];
if (currentRect.origin.y > previousRect.origin.y) {
              [self adjustTextViewHeightToString:textView];
    }
    previousRect = currentRect;
}
```

It is not the most efficient way but will update table view rarely.

Comment: Thanks. This really help me. The `currentRect.origin.y > previousRect.origin.y` didn't work for me. I changed it to `currentRect.origin.x == 0` and it worked. When the cursor reach the width of the 'UITextView' it creates a new line and starts all over again. The problem with the previous condition was that the y origin don't change when the cursor is not visible in the `UITextView`.